# GCP Datafusion upload custom plugin is too slow

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Currently I am using basic edition of datafusion and i wanted to upload a custom plugin. It is too slow to upload the jar and json. Taking around 10 minutes of time to upload the plugin and entire browser is getting hanged. 
Did anyone faced this issue before and how are you able to deal with it.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on the type of plugin you are customizing? Accorind to the documentation you have some types to choose from, [here](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/current/en/developer-manual/pipelines/developing-plugins/plugin-basics.html#plugin-types).

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, I cloned HTTP plugin from data-integrations/http repo and i ran mvn clean install -DskipTests. The size of the JAR is 44.65 MB. I am using windows machine

Comment: have you checked your network connection? Also, can you try to install your plugin using  Rest API call ? You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest).

Answer (score 0):

Whats the size of plugin jar you are trying to upload? Also what is the version of CDF you are using?

Comment: I cloned HTTP plugin from data-integrations/http repo and i ran mvn clean install -DskipTests. The size of the JAR is 44.65 MB. I am using windows machine.